# Compare full rows between two CSV files based on a single column as index and output when rows don't match

Tags: csv

I have two CSV files with identical columns but not identical rows and I would like to output when a row indexed on the first column doesn't match another row.

Headers are:

```
appUser.userName,user.firstName,user.lastName,user.fullName,user.email,user.mobilePhone,user.secondEmail,user.login,user.primaryPhone,user.streetAddress,user.city,user.state,user.zipCode,user.countryCode,user.postalAddress,user.locale
```

So if there's a match between `appUser.userName` in both files, compare the values for all columns and if there's a difference, output the two rows highlighting the differences.